# How to enable smart commit for custom workflow in JIRA?

Tags: git, jira, bitbucket, dvcs

We're using custom workflow as attached. 
In the example from JIRA official we have a clear and easy to understand instruction on how to trigger the smart commit and update the ticket status in JIRA. Unfortunately seem like it's not working with the custom workflow or is there any way to work around? advise is appreciated.

```
JRA-090 #close Fixed this today
```

Reference from [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACLOUD/Processing+JIRA+issues+with+commit+messages)

[image: Our custom workflow]

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some examples of what you have tried? You should be able to use a smart commit transition with a custom workflow. You need to make sure you replace the whitespaces with -

I would recommend trying something like:

*JIRA-123 #Start-Development Your comment here*

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but there's a couple of things to note:

1. The DVCS connection is not instant; it defaults to syncing every hour. Enabling webhooks can shorten the time:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/slow-appearing-commits-from-bitbucket-or-github-in-jira-779160823.html

2. The email address of the repository user MUST match a user in JIRA who has appropriate access to trigger the transition.  For example, some people have GitHub accounts that don't match their JIRA accounts, which means the GitHub account email isn't in the JIRA user directory. This means the user doesn't have "Close Issue" permission.  The message "Fixed this today" will still appear in the JIRA issue, but the Close transition doesn't happen.

Hope these are helpful!